# Deleting document(s) inside a collection with documentReference

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firebase called "community" and "events".
When an event document is created, a field "communityRef" is included as docRef to community.

I'm trying to figure a code that when a community is deleted, all events related to the community are also deleted.

building this in flutterflow using custom action

onTap on a button in UI, the code is included as one of the actions before community document is deleted.

```
Future deleteAllRefEvents(DocumentReference community) async {
  final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final batch = instance.batch();
  var collection = instance.collection('events');
  var snapshots = await collection.where('communityRef', isEqualTo: DocumentReference).get();
  for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
    batch.delete(doc.reference);
  }
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: What is question or doubt here?

Comment: the code doesn't work. Not sure what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `DocumentReference` type instead of variable `community`

Your code should be as following

```
Future deleteAllRefEvents(DocumentReference community) async {
  final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final batch = instance.batch();
  var collection = instance.collection('events');
  var snapshots = await collection.where('communityRef', isEqualTo: community).get();//Here you used DocumentReference instead of community
  for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
    batch.delete(doc.reference);
  }
  await batch.commit();
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. An extension to the same problem above - All user documents have a field <List> "joinedCommunity". I need to delete just the community docRef from the <List>"joinedCommunity" from ALL user records. Being careful to not delete the user document. I don't have the code for that yet

Comment: You can either write cloud_function or remove all from here to handle this